# NServiceBus: Object reference exception from NServiceBus.Host

Tags: nservicebus

I am getting an exception when I try to start a modified version of the PubSub sample.  I am trying to do a few things like making subscription not automatic, and injecting my own ISubscriptionStorage implementation.  Here is what I did to MyPublisher\EndpointConfig.cs:

```
using NServiceBus;
using NServiceBus.Grid.MessageHandlers;
using NServiceBus.ObjectBuilder;
using NServiceBus.Sagas.Impl;

namespace MyPublisher
{
    class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, IWantCustomInitialization
    {
        public void Init()
        {
            NServiceBus.Configure.With()
                .DefaultBuilder()
                .XmlSerializer()
                .UnicastBus()
                .LoadMessageHandlers(First<GridInterceptingMessageHandler>.Then<SagaMessageHandler>())
                .DoNotAutoSubscribe();

            NServiceBus.Configure.Instance.Configurer.ConfigureComponent<StreamSubscriptionStorage>(ComponentCallModelEnum.Singleton);
        }
    }
}
```

It used to be this:

```
using NServiceBus;
using NServiceBus.Grid.MessageHandlers;
using NServiceBus.Sagas.Impl;

namespace MyPublisher
{
    class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Publisher, 
        ISpecifyMessageHandlerOrdering
    {
        public void SpecifyOrder(Order order) 
        {
            order.Specify(First<GridInterceptingMessageHandler>.Then<SagaMessageHandler>());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to include the .MsmqTransport() in your custom initialization.

Comment: Thanks, Udi.  Do think it would be a good idea to log a bug against NServiceBus for a more informative error message in this case?